# Calling a 'non-static string' from ouside the individual page model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I'm using .net core Razor pages, and I'm trying to write a class / function to look up CMS data from database. I can get it work if I put the class into the model.cs of each page, but I really want to just call it from a central class file.

The code that I have that works is:

```
/// on the .cs model page: 
namespace TestFrontEnd.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly TestFrontEnd.Data.EventContext _context;

        public IndexModel(TestFrontEnd.Data.EventContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public string GetByTitle(string CMSTitle, int PageType = 0)
        {
            var CMSEntry = _context.CMSFieldList
                .Where(a => a.Title.ToLower() == CMSTitle.ToLower())
                .Include(a => a.CMSEntries.Where(b => b.PageType == PageType ))
                .AsNoTracking()
                .FirstOrDefault();

            string ReturnText = "";

            if (CMSEntry != null)
            {
                if (CMSEntry.CMSEntries.Any())
                {
                    ReturnText = CMSEntry.CMSEntries.First().CEntry;
                }
            }
            return ReturnText;
        }
    }
}

//On the Index.cshtml page:
@Model.GetByTitle("MainHeader")
```

This works just as I want it to - looks up the CMS entry in my database with the Title 'MainHeader' and returns the entry into the page. What I want to do is be able to call this on any page without having to copy the same 'public string GetByTitle...' code into each page model. I've created the following EventCMS class page:

```
namespace TestFrontEnd.Pages
{
    public class EventCMS
    {
        private readonly TestFrontEnd.Data.EventContext _context;

        public EventCMS(TestFrontEnd.Data.EventContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public string GetByTitle(string CMSTitle, int PageType = 0)
        {
            var CMSEntry = _context.CMSFieldList
                .Where(a => a.Title.ToLower() == CMSTitle.ToLower())
                .Include(a => a.CMSEntries.Where(b => b.PageType == PageType ))
                .AsNoTracking()
                .FirstOrDefault();

            string ReturnText = "";

            if (CMSEntry != null)
            {
                if (CMSEntry.CMSEntries.Any())
                {
                    ReturnText = CMSEntry.CMSEntries.First().CEntry;
                }
            }
            return ReturnText;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to call it on a Razor page using something like  `@EventCMS.GetByTitle("MainHeader")`  but I get a 'CS0120 : An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property' error.

If I make it a static string without the database lookup it works fine

```
public static string GetByTitle(string CMSTitle, int PageType = 0)
        {
            string ReturnText = "";

            if (CMSTitle.ToLower() == "mainheader")
            {
                ReturnText = "This is my static main header";
            }
            return ReturnText;
        }
```

I'm obviously missing something fundamental, but I'm quite new to .net / c#, previously having written in classic ASP, so if anyone can point me in the right direction for achiveing this, that would be much appricated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Startup.cs file, in the ConfigureServices method, you have to register the dependency for EventCMS:

```
services.AddSingleton<EventCMS>();
```

than you have to inject this dependency in all the classes who need to use the methods of this class:

```
namespace TestFrontEnd.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly TestFrontEnd.Data.EventContext _context;
        public EventCMS EventCMS { get; }
        public IndexModel(TestFrontEnd.Data.EventContext context, EventCMS eventCMS)
        {
            _context = context;
            EventCMS = eventCMS;
        }

        
    }
}
```

And than you can use it in your cshtml

```
//On the Index.cshtml page:
@Model.EventCMS.GetByTitle("MainHeader")
```

Comment: Thanks for this - This sent me in the right direction and with the help of [link](https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/51939451/how-to-use-a-database-context-in-a-singleton-service-) I added in a scope to pull the database into the EventCMS singleton class.